# Почему картинка не отображается?

Tags: html, css

Почему картинка не отображается?
html

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

css

```
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
.block {
    background: url('img/bg.jpg') 50%/cover no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего некорректно установили путь до файла или формат файлы не корректно указан. css рабочий. Путь к файлу от файла с html  - img/background/bg.jpg? уверены?

Answer (score 0):

В папке с html файлом должна присутствовать папка img с файлом bg.jpg, а у вас там его судя по всему нет. Проверить это легко - достаточно поставить ссылку на реальное изображение. Например возьмём ссылку на изображение из интернета:

```css
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
.block {
    background: url('https://sun9-3.userapi.com/c851420/v851420625/ab90c/EjFmBdujxUU.jpg') 50%/cover no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```